# Add a bit map image to Radio Button in vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I need to add a bit map image to a radio button in MFC . i have no idea on how to do it 
can any one tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this helpful:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/cbuttonst.aspx

Thanks.